# Locate row in DataGridView when bound DataView sorted by different column in .NET

Tags: c#, winforms, sorting, datagridview, datatable

I have a DataGridView with a DataTable set to its DataSource.  The DataTable has two columns.  The user has a TextBox which dynamically (after each keypress) searches for a match in the first column.
I want to jump to the matching record (if any) after each key entry, so it needs to be fast.
I use the Find() method on the DefaultView of the DataTable.  I then position the Currency Manager, which causes the DataGridView to jump to the correct record.

However, this all breaks when the user elects to sort by the second column.  That changes the sort in the DefaultView, and Find() can no longer search on the first column.

If I create a second DataView which is always sorted by the first column, the I can always perform Find(), but then I do not know how to identify the corresponding record in the DataGridView.

Is there a way to use Find() on a column in the DataTable despite the bound DataView being sorted by a different column, and still jump to the found row in the DataGridView?

Answer (score 0):

Think about the problem again, when data is not sorted on the first column (even if it is done by framework) linear search O(n) is the best suited for your problem. Using this I've implemented following demo code which solves your problem, just add DataGridView & TextBox to your form, setup event handlers, you should be seeing the behavior you're looking for with below code. `This is not production quality code, rather directon on howto solve your problem in smaller context`.

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// You can optimize this functionality only when the first column is sorted. 
        /// If not there is no faster way other than linear search, even if it would be done by framework, in my opinion linear search is the best posssible solution when the first column is not sorted.
        /// This piece of code is for demo purposes on how to do something, should be refined to fit your production cases.
        /// </summary>
        private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string text = textBox1.Text.Trim();
            int index = dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex;
            CurrencyManager cm = dataGridView1.BindingContext[dataGridView1.DataSource] as CurrencyManager;
            DataView view = cm.List as DataView;

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(text)) return;

            //If sorted on first column
            if (view.Sort.Contains("First")) //column will be "[First]"
            {
                index = source.DefaultView.Find(text);
                SetIndex(cm, index);
            }
            //if not
            else if (view.Sort.Contains("Second")) //column will be "[Second]"
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    if (dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["First"].Value.ToString().StartsWith(text))
                    {
                        index = i; break;
                    }
                }
                SetIndex(cm, index);
            }
        }

        private void SetIndex(CurrencyManager cm, int index)
        {
            if (index >= 0 && index < source.Rows.Count)
            {
                cm.Position = index;
            }
        }

        private void CreateData()
        {
            source.Columns.Add("First", typeof(string));
            source.Columns.Add("Second", typeof(string));

            var f = from first in Enumerable.Range('a', 26)
                    select new string(new char[] { (char)first });

            var s = f.Reverse();

            var c1Enumerator = f.GetEnumerator();
            var c2Enumerator = s.GetEnumerator();

            for (int i = 0; i < f.Count(); i++)
            {
                DataRow dr = source.NewRow();
                c1Enumerator.MoveNext();
                c2Enumerator.MoveNext();

                dr[0] = c1Enumerator.Current;
                dr[1] = c2Enumerator.Current;
                source.Rows.Add(dr);
            }
        }

        DataTable source = new DataTable();

        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CreateData();
            dataGridView1.DataSource = source;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

It's a bit simpler if you use a BindingSource:

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;

public class Form1 : Form
{
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new Form1());
    }

    BindingSource source;

    public Form1()
    {
        Controls.Add(new DataGridView { Name = "DGV", Dock = DockStyle.Fill, TabIndex = 2 });
        Controls.Add(new TextBox { Name = "Find", Dock = DockStyle.Top, TabIndex = 1 });

        DataTable table = CreateData();
        source = new BindingSource(table, null);
        (Controls["DGV"] as DataGridView).DataSource = source;
        source.Sort = "First";

        Controls["Find"].TextChanged += (s, e) =>
            {
                int index = source.Find("First", (s as Control).Text);
                if (index >= 0)
                    source.Position = index;
            };
    }

    private DataTable CreateData()
    {
        DataTable table = new DataTable { Columns = { "First", "Second" } };
        foreach (var o in Enumerable.Range('a', 26).Select(ch => new { F = new String((char)ch, 1), S = new String((char)('z' - (ch - 'a')), 1)}))
        {
            DataRow dr = table.NewRow();
            dr[0] = o.F;
            dr[1] = o.S;
            table.Rows.Add(dr);
        };
        return table;
    }
}
```